# Google Appscript autofill another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I don't know if this is a bit of a complicated one. My google form is linked to a google sheet and I have a script that when a form is submitted it copies a google doc template and automatically fills in the relevant parts.

What I'd like is that instead of filling a doc template, it fills a sheet template. My script is currently set up to look for specific text in the document and replace it with the relevant cell information

Comment: How can we help?

Comment: Did you write the script?

Comment: No I managed to find the script that does that online. Let me know if it would be useful to see what i'm using

Answer (score 0):

You can use [createTextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createTextFinder(String)) and then get the range of the current match of the [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

```
function getText() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let text = sheet.createTextFinder("{{IS_5}}");
    console.log(text.findNext().getA1Notation());
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

8:19:03 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:19:04 AM  Info    A6
8:19:04 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Here is a simple onFormSubmit(e) installed trigger.  It gets the latest event info, copies a spreadsheet template and replaces the string {{value}} with the form value.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  try {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    let copy = spread.copy("Copy of "+spread.getName());  // copy the template
    let text = copy.createTextFinder("{{value}}");
    let range = text.findNext();
    range.setValue(e.namedValues.Test[0]);
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

Reference

- [Spreadsheet.copy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copy(String))
- [Spreadsheet.createTextFinder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#createTextFinder(String))
- [Range.setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object))
- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have no experience with script. Which sheet would i be adding this script too?

Comment: You said you are currently filling in a Doc.  I'm assuming you were using `findText()'.  This is how to find text in a spreadsheet.

Comment: No, i'm using body.replaceText

Comment: You must have a script that gets the form response and copies to a Doc.  Now all you need to do is get the form response and copy to another spreadsheet using the `Range` of the found text and replace with the response.  You don't show enough of anything for me to help more.

Comment: I tried to post the full script but it was too long. How do I post a photo on here?

Comment: I can not image how a script to do what you are asking for can be that long.

Comment: I've added an example of copying a value from form submittal to a copy of a spreadsheet template.  If this doesn't suit your needs then I don't know what does.